# Manually write an audio file

Tags: audio

I want to write an audio file (the particular format does not matter to me) by hand i.e. for each frame I would write manually which frequencies are present at which intensity. How do I do this? Is there some specialized software for this?

Answer (score 1):

You have the `sox` command with limited synthesizing ability.

Ex `sox -n a.wav  synth 6 sine 440` generate a 6s 440Hz file.

Once all your fragment files are created, use `sox a1.wav a2.wav … result.wav` to assemble.

See also https://sound.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

There might be many solutions depending on what exactly you want to achieve.

Most DAWs, even as simple as Audacity, allow to draw the waveform manually, e.g. using the mouse.

Various data analysis software, e.g. Matlab/Octave have libraries allowing to write any kind of data to an audio file, see e.g. https://octave.org/doc/v4.4.1/Audio-File-Utilities.html

Finally, for a more musician friendly interface, there are countless free and commercial software synthesizers available in various formats, allowing to produce very simple, or very complex waveforms.